# How is memory space kept different between processes?

Tags: memory, pagination, operating-system, virtual-memory

> How is memory space between processes kept separate?

I am confused how this works exactly. From what I see, thinking about MMU and virtual memory,

the CPU generates a virtual-address, which is then mapped to either somewhere in the Disk or some page in the RAM. But how exactly is the memory space kept separate?

Comment: The address is not mapped, it is translated to physical one. To answer your unclear question, it is the CPU.

Comment: @Tony, yes I meant it is translate to a physical one from virtual/logical. As for the actual question, can you elaborate what you mean by "CPU?" I dont understand how memory space is kept separate

Comment: In the translation process, some more bits are kept per entry. If two different processes have their pages mapped to the same slot, then one of them will have his bits set off. So he won't be able to access that page. Unless his page is brought to memory and the other one is swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

You are highly confused here. The operating system maintains page tables that do the mapping of logical pages to physical page frames. Each process sees logical pages numbered 0 ... N that may or may not be mapped to physical page frames. The MMU uses the page tables to do the translation.

Process X can access page #2 and Process Y can access page #2 but they will usually map to different physical page frames. By mapping the same logical address to different physical pages, the operating system keeps the processes separated.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the mapping, BUT each process has its own page table doesnt it? So page 2 for Process X and different for Page 2 from Process Y. The doubt I was having is, how exactly is memory kept seperate? Meaning, how are registers, stack-frame etc kept separate for processes?

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia changing processes means extracting the values of the registers and saving them in the process task struct. Once that process returns to run, its values are read from the task struct and copied to the registers so it continue from where it stopped.